# INVALID_QUERY on logzio for sub aggregate

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, logz.io

App logs are stored on logz.io
I'm trying to aggregate the error logs from my app, for each version, I would like to aggregate the error messsages.
I tried using a sub aggregate query:

```
curl -X POST https://api.logz.io/v1/search \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-API-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxx' \
  -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {"@timestamp": { "gte": "now-2w", "lte": "now"}}
        }
      ],
      "filter": [{"terms": {"log_level": ["ERROR","CRITICAL","FATAL"]}}]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "app_version_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "app_version",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
          "error_message_agg": {
              "terms": {
              "field": "error_message",
              "size": 1000
              }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

but I get this error:

```
{"errorCode":"LogzElasticsearchAPI/INVALID_QUERY","message":"This search can't be executed: [Bad Request]. Please contact customer support for more details","requestId":"xxxx","parameters":{"reason":"Bad Request"}}
```

I will note that when I use multiple aggregations on same level, I do get results, (but results are separate aggregations and not aggregation according to a few fields)

```
curl -X POST https://api.logz.io/v1/search \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-API-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxx' \
  -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {"@timestamp": { "gte": "now-2w", "lte": "now"}}
        }
      ],
      "filter": [{"terms": {"log_level": ["ERROR","CRITICAL","FATAL"]}}]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "app_version_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "app_version",
        "size": 1000
      }
    },
    "error_message_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "error_message",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Logz.io documentation for the [search endpoint](https://docs.logz.io/api/#operation/search), there's a limitation for aggregations:

> Can't nest 2 or more bucket aggregations of these types: date_histogram, geohash_grid, histogram, ip_ranges, significant_terms, terms

So that probably explains the issue you're encountering.